# Subset list of dataframes containing specific column name

Tags: r, list, subset, lapply, purrr

I have a list of dataframes and I'd like to get column `x` from each dataframe as a string.

```
testing <- list(data.frame(A = "Yes", B = "No"),
                data.frame(B = "No", C = "No"),
                data.frame(A = "Yes"))
```

I can print which of the dataframes have a `colname` A in them, but I haven't been able to make the connection to subsetting the original testing

```
lapply(testing, function(x) "A" %in% colnames(x))
```

## Desired Output

```
[[1]]
    A  B
1 Yes No

[[2]]
    A
1 Yes
```

Comment: If you have column names such as `c("A", "AB", "CA")` be aware that the accepted answer will give you back all those columns. Check `grepl("A", x = c("A", "AB", "ABC"), fixed = TRUE)` versus `c("A", "AB", "CA") %in% "A"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option involving `purrr` could be:

```
keep(testing, ~ any(grepl("A", names(.), fixed = TRUE)))

[[1]]
    A  B
1 Yes No

[[2]]
    A
1 Yes
```

Or:

```
keep(testing, ~ sum(names(.) == "A") != 0)
```

If the desired output is indeed to have the A column return as a string, with the addition of `dplyr`:

```
map(keep(testing, ~ any(grepl("A", names(.), fixed = TRUE))), ~ .x %>%
     pull(A) %>%
     as.character())

[[1]]
[1] "Yes"

[[2]]
[1] "Yes"
```

Or:

```
map(keep(testing, ~ sum(names(.) == "A") != 0), ~ .x %>%
     pull(A) %>%
     as.character())
```

Answer (score 7):

Another base option is `Filter`

```
out <- Filter(function(x) "A" %in% names(x), testing)
out
#[[1]]
#    A  B
#1 Yes No
#
#[[2]]
#    A
#1 Yes
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `sapply` to create a logical `vector` and subset

```
testing[sapply(testing, function(x) "A" %in% colnames(x))]
```